# Copy the value of a row in the previous row R

Tags: r, copy, dataset, row

I have a big dataset **df**; its short version looks like this:

```
Time    Block   Accuracy
6087.8  Run2    NA
633.2   Run2    NA
547     Run2    incorrect
135.2   Run2    NA
6217.6  Run2    NA
175.2   Run2    NA
179     Run2    incorrect
```

I want to copy the value *incorrect* in the previous row of df$Accuracy, so it would look like this:

```
Time    Block   Accuracy
6087.8  Run2    NA
633.2   Run2    incorrect
547     Run2    incorrect
135.2   Run2    NA
6217.6  Run2    NA
175.2   Run2    incorrect
179     Run2    incorrect
```

What is the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the rows that will be affected, run:

```
which(df$Accuracy == "incorrect")-1
```

`which()` returns the elements of a vector that are true for a particular boolean statement (in this case, which values of Accuracy are equal to incorrect). We then minus 1 from each value in the vector to get the previous row positions.

We can then modify them:

```
df[which(df$Accuracy == "incorrect")-1, "Accuracy"] <- "incorrect"
```

This finds all the rows as above, and says: for those rows and the column "Accuracy", replace the values with "incorrect".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding `"incorrect"` , you can just make value below each `NA` to shift up.

```
na_bool = is.na(df$Accuracy)
df[na_bool,]$Accuracy = df[c(FALSE,na_bool[-length(na_bool)]),]$Accuracy
```